# How to implement minibatch gradient descent in tensorflow without using feeddict?

Tags: tensorflow

From what I understand, using `feed_dict` is a computationally expensive process and should be avoided according to [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428). Tensorflow's input pipelines are supposedly better.

All mini-batch gradient descent tutorials that I've found are implemented with `feed_dict`. Is there a way to use input pipelines and minibatch gradient descent?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just making a small model, you will do fine with `feed_dict`. Many large models have been trained with the `feed_dict` method in the past. If you are scaling to a very deep convnet with a large dataset or something, you may want to use `tf.data` and the dataset pipeline, probably with the dataset serialized to a `.tfrecord` file so that the data can be pre-fetched to the GPU to reduce idle time. These optimizations are worthwhile with large models, and if you would really like to learn the API, visit the [quickstart guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/datasets_quickstart) and [this helpful Medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428) on getting started with the API.